# Using powershell, how do I extract a 7-digit number from a subject-line (of an email ), regular expressions?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have the following code which lists the first 5 items in the Inbox folder (of Outlook).

How would I extract only the number portion of it( say - 7 digit arbitrary numberss, which are embedded within other text)? Then using Powershell commands, I'd really like to take those extracted numbers and dump them to a CSV file(thus, they can be easily incorporated into an existing spreadsheet I use).

Here's what I tried :

```
$outlook = new-object -com Outlook.Application
$sentMail = $outlook.Session.GetDefaultFolder(6) # == olFolderInbox
$sentMail.Items | select -last 10 TaskSubject    # ideally, grabbing first 20

 $matches2 =  "\d+$"
 $res = gc $sentMail.Items | ?{$_ -match $matches2 | %{ $_ -match $matches2 | out-null; $matches[1] }
```

but this does not run correctly, but rather .. keeps me hanging with awaiting-input symbol: like so :

```
>>
>>
>>
```

Do I need to perhaps create a separate variable in between the 1st part and 2nd part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what the `$matches` variable is for but try to replace your last line with something like below.

For Subject Line Items:

```
$sentMail.Items | % { $_.TaskSubject | Select-String -Pattern '^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}' | % {([string]$_).Substring(0,12)} }
```

For Message Body Items:

```
$sentMail.Items | % { ($_.Body).Split("`n") | Select-String -Pattern '^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}' |% {([string]$_).Substring(0,12)}  }
```

Here is a refrence to Select-String which I use pretty often.
https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849903.aspx

Here is a reference to the Phone number portion which I have never used but found pretty cool.
http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/03/24/use-powershell-to-search-a-group-of-files-for-phone-numbers.aspx

Good luck!

---

Here is an edited version for 7 digit extraction via subject line. This assumes the number has a space on each side but can be modified a bit if necessary. You may also want to adjust the depth by changing the -First portion to Select * or just making 100 deeper in range.

```
$outlook = New-Object -com Outlook.Application
$Mail = $outlook.Session.GetDefaultFolder(6) # Folder Inbox

$Mail.Items | select -First 100 TaskSubject | 
% { $_.TaskSubject | Select-String -Pattern '\s\d{7}\s'} |
% {((Select-String -InputObject $_ -Pattern '\s\d{7}\s').Line).split(" ") | 
% {if(($_.Length -eq 7) -and ($_ -match '\d{7}')) {$_ | Out-File -FilePath "C:\Temp\SomeFile.csv" -Append}}}
```

Comment: Haha you paste these reference to to technet, but also state you don't know what $matches is for?

From technet:
"The $Matches variable works with the -match and -notmatch operators.
       When you submit scalar input to the -match or -notmatch operator, and
       either one detects a match, they return a Boolean value and populate
       the $Matches automatic variable with a hash table of any string values
       that were matched. For more information about the -match pperator, see 
       about_comparison_operators."

Comment: I guess I didn't acknowledge the $matches2 variable as a regex statement. My bad.

Comment: "The $Matches variable works with the -match and -notmatch operators. When you submit scalar input to the -match or -notmatch operator, and either one detects a match, they return a Boolean value and populate the $Matches automatic variable with a hash table of any string values that were matched. For more information about the -match pperator, see about_comparison_operators."  - from technet

Comment: @ssaviers -  thanks so much  ! I updated the question a little bit, pplus added a new bounty. Apologies ,  Ichanged it a little bit. I want to take out 7 digit numbers , and possibly  dump to  CSV file

Comment: Granted this is from my phone and I can't test but something like this maybe and I cant mark up with code blocks. $sentMail.Items | % { $_.TaskSubject | Select-String -Pattern '^\d{7}' | export-csv "c:\temp\somefile.csv" -notypeinformation -append}

Answer (score 1):

*Some* of this you have already addressed / figured out but I wanted to explain the issues with your current code.

If you expect multiple matches and want to return those then you would need to use `Select-String` with the `-AllMatches` parameter. Your regex, in your example, is currently looking for a sequence of digits at the end of the subject. That would only return one match so lets looks at the issues with your code.

```powershell
$sentMail.Items | select -last 10 TaskSubject
```

You are filtering the last 10 items but you are not storing those for later use so they would merely be displayed on screen. We cover a solution later.

One of the primary reasons for using `-match` is to get the Boolean value that is returned for code like `if` blocks and `where` clauses. You can still use it in the way you intended. Looking at the current code in question:

```powershell
$res = gc $sentMail.Items | ?{$_ -match $matches2 | %{ $_ -match $matches2 | out-null; $matches[1] }
```

The two big issues with this are you are calling `Get-Content`(`gc`) on each item. `Get-Content` is for pulling file data which `$sentMail.Items` is not. You also having a *large* where block. Where blocks will pass data to the output steam based on a true or false condition. Your malformed statement `?{$_ -match $matches2 | %{ $_ -match $matches2 | out-null; $matches[1] }` wont do this... at least not well.

```powershell
$outlook = new-object -com Outlook.Application
$sentMail = $outlook.Session.GetDefaultFolder(6) # == olFolderInbox
$matches2 =  "\d+$"
$sentMail.Items | select -last 10 -ExpandProperty TaskSubject | ?{$_ -match $matches2} | %{$Matches[0]}
```

Take the last 10 email subjects and check if either of them match the regex string `$matches2`. *If* they do then return the string match to standard output.